# How to tar directory and then remove originals including the directory?

Tags: linux, tar

I'm trying to `tar` a collection of files in a directory called 'my_directory' and remove the originals by using the command:

```
tar -cvf files.tar my_directory --remove-files
```

However it is only removing the individual files inside the directory and not the directory itself (which is what I specified in the command). What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**

Yes, I suppose the 'remove-files' option is fairly literal. Although I too found the man page unclear on that point. (In linux I tend not to really distinguish much between directories and files that much, and forget sometimes that they are not the same thing). It looks like the consensus is that it doesn't remove directories.

However, my major prompting point for asking this question stems from tar's handling of absolute paths. Because you must specify a relative path to a file/s to be compressed, you therefore must change to the parent directory to tar it properly. As I see it using any kind of follow-on 'rm' command is potentially dangerous in that situation. Thus I was hoping to simplify things by making tar itself do the remove.

For example, imagine a backup script where the directory to backup (ie. tar) is included as a shell variable. If that shell variable value was badly entered, it is possible that the result could be deleted files from whatever directory you happened to be in last.

Comment: Nicholas, your point that it adds danger to have to remove the directory tree in an extra step is absolutely valid. I think it should be possible to have this done safely by the archiver. I also believe this was the intention of the creators of GNU tar, at least it should have been ;-)

Comment: I've found that the --remove-files option does indeed remove the containing dir - at least on some platforms/in some versions - and in my case. Might be that in your case the remaining dir wasn't completely empty due to some files being modified after being tar'ed.

Comment: @isync I seem to be experiencing --remove-files deleting directories on Ubuntu 14.04. Except in my case I don't want it to. Haha

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are missing the part which says the `--remove-files` option removes **files** after adding them to the archive.

You could follow the archive and file-removal operation with a command like,

> find /path/to/be/archived/ -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;

---

Update: You may be interested in reading this short Debian discussion on,
[Bug 424692: --remove-files complains that directories "changed as we read it"](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=424692).

Comment: Maybe it's actually: `-c` changes directory before `tar` starts its work (and kind of does not return until done)? I *guess* it would have deleted subdirectories, if those were included in the archive (but I have not tested that).

Comment: @Arajan, I do not think '`c'` has anything to do with this; `'remove-files'` intentionally does not remove directories.

Comment: Aha, I find the short explanation "remove files after adding them to the archive" from the `man` pages not too clear on that, but I assume you're right. Still, I'd not expect the directory mentioned for `-c` to be removed even *if* `tar` did remove directories as well. (To me, that would be like removing the current directory, hence including the archive itself, when *not* using `-c`...?) But if `-remove-files` always leaves directories in place then I'm surely just complicating things here. ;-)

Comment: `--remove-files` bug was fixed in [`tar-1.19`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=424692#14).

Answer (score 28):

Since the `--remove-files` option only *removes files*, you could try

```
tar -cvf files.tar my_directory && rm -R my_directory
```

so that the directory is removed only if the `tar` returns an exit status of 0

Comment: except that you should check the exit status of tar before doing the rm! otherwise you might be left with no tar archive and no files...

Comment: When using one level directories, I beleive a safer option would be using 'rmdir' rather than 'rm' to as it would only remove an empty directory. [See question edits]

Comment: But `rmdir` only removes *empty* directories. The idea was to remove the directory *and* the files in it (provided `tar` is successful)

Comment: `--remove-files` bug was fixed in [`tar-1.19`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=424692#14).

Comment: && will only run the following command, if the previous command exited 0 (success). If it exits > 0, the following command won't be run.
You can also reverse that with || -- only run if the first command failed. Good way to do terrible content check-restarts that one.

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried to put --remove-files directive after archive name? It works for me.

```
tar -cvf files.tar --remove-files my_directory
```

Comment: It's more likely that the behavior of tar has changed since this question was posed. For me, there's no difference in putting `--remove-files` before or after `my_directory`; in both cases, the directory is removed.

Comment: `--remove-files` bug was fixed in [`tar-1.19`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=424692#14).

Answer (score 1):

```
source={directory argument}
```

e.g.

```
source={FULL ABSOLUTE PATH}/my_directory
```

```
parent={parent directory of argument}
```

e.g.

```
parent={ABSOLUTE PATH of 'my_directory'/
```

```
logFile={path to a run log that captures status messages}
```

Then you could execute something along the lines of:

```
cd ${parent}

tar cvf Tar_File.`date%Y%M%D_%H%M%S` ${source}

if [ $? != 0 ]

then

 echo "Backup FAILED for ${source} at `date` >> ${logFile}

else

 echo "Backup SUCCESS for ${source} at `date` >> ${logFile}

 rm -rf ${source}

fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This was probably a bug.

Also the word "file" is ambigous in this case. But because this is a command line switch I would it expect to mean also directories, because in unix/lnux everything is a file, also a directory. (The other interpretation is of course also valid, but It makes no sense to keep directories in such a case. I would consider it unexpected and confusing behavior.)

But I have found that in gnu tar on some distributions gnu tar actually removes the directory tree. Another indication that keeping the tree was a bug. Or at least some workaround until they fixed it.

This is what I tried out on an ubuntu 10.04 console:

```
mit:/var/tmp$ mkdir tree1                                                                                               
mit:/var/tmp$ mkdir tree1/sub1                                                                                          
mit:/var/tmp$ > tree1/sub1/file1                                                                                        

mit:/var/tmp$ ls -la                                                                                                    
drwxrwxrwt  4 root root 4096 2011-11-14 15:40 .                                                                              
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4096 2011-02-25 03:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 mit  mit  4096 2011-11-14 15:40 tree1

mit:/var/tmp$ tar -czf tree1.tar.gz tree1/ --remove-files

# AS YOU CAN SEE THE TREE IS GONE NOW:

mit:/var/tmp$ ls -la
drwxrwxrwt  3 root root 4096 2011-11-14 15:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4096 2011-02-25 03:15 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 mit   mit    159 2011-11-14 15:41 tree1.tar.gz                                                                   


mit:/var/tmp$ tar --version                                                                                             
tar (GNU tar) 1.22                                                                                                           
Copyright © 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

If you want to see it on your machine, paste this into a console at your own risk:

```
tar --version                                                                                             
cd /var/tmp
mkdir -p tree1/sub1                                                                                          
> tree1/sub1/file1                                                                                        
tar -czf tree1.tar.gz tree1/ --remove-files
ls -la
```